# Is it possible to directly reference the Source Data of a Pivot Table?

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have a large table of data on Sheet1 and a pivot table on Sheet2 that is based on Sheet1. I would like to be able to jump from a selected PivotItem on Sheet2 directly to the cell on Sheet1 that the data is from. So far I just use

```
EID = ActiveCell.PivotTable.PivotFields(1).DataRange.Cells(ActiveCell.PivotCell.PivotRowLine.Position, 1).Text
Set rTarget = Sheet1.Columns(1).Find(EID, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True)
Sheet1.activate
rTarget.activate
```

Which is a little messy because my current strategy to locate the data is the unique identifier in PivotFields(1) but I want to allow the user to select any cell along the Row. So I have to reference the cell address in PivotFields(1) in the same row and then search for it in Sheet1.

I would prefer to avoid using Cells.Find and was wondering if there was a method or property that might allow me to do something like:

```
set rTarget = Activecell.PivotItem.SourceDataRange
```

Where SourceDataRange would return the Range of the cell in Sheet1 that is supplying the data for the pivotitem. PivotTable.SourceData returns the entire range. I am looking for the range of an individual pivotitem.

Does such a method exist?

Comment: AFAIK there is no such property in the Object Model.

Comment: How would this work unless there is a 1-2-1 relationship as pivots aggregate rows of data? A 1-2-1 is basically the table. Sounds like what you really want is the drilldown range you get when double clicking on an item in the pivottable databodyrange.

Comment: I think you would need to write some custom vba as I don't see anything listed in the methods of range or pivotitem.